# Segmentation fault in my strcpy

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, strcpy

I'm writing my own `strcpy` due to the fact that the default one in `string.h` only accept a `const char *` as a source string to copy from.
I'm trying this very basic prototype (yes, the return isn't meaningful, I'm just trying things):

```
int copyStrings(char * dest, char * source){
    int i=0;
    while(source[i]!='\0'){
        dest[i]=source[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

and it gives me `SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault` error in gdb, at the line `dest[i]=source[i]`, right at the *first* character. I'm pretty sure `dest[i]` isn't a string literal, so I should be able to modify it.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: here's the calling

```
int main(){
    char * str = (char*)malloc((int)sizeof(double));
    char * str2 = (char *)malloc((int)sizeof(int));
    str = "hello";
    str2 = "hey jude";
    copyStrings(str2, str);
    free(str);
    free(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the caller. BTW, it should return something meaningful.

Comment: What's the problem with `strcpy()` only accepting a `const char *`?  You can pass a non-const `char *` to the function and the function simply promises it won't change the data via that `const char *`.  It does no harm; you can pass const or non-const strings as the second argument.

Comment: The default `strcpy` is also going to be faster too

Comment: What the size of `int` and `double` have to do with strings? Also you assign both of them with string literals afterwards.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm trying to make sure that they both have enough space to store chars.

Comment: Since `malloc()` expects a `size_t` argument, your `(int)` casts on the result of `sizeof` are odd.  The string `"hey jude"` is 9 bytes long; on most machines, `sizeof(double)` is `8` (and `sizeof(int)` is usually `4`).  That's a probable cause of trouble.  You're leaking memory; and you **ARE** trying to assign to constants (string literals).  You need to use `strcpy()` to assign `"hello"` and `"hey jude"` — and you need to make sure you've got enough space to copy the strings into.  Hint: you've not allocated enough space.  Change your `sizeof()` operands to `16`.  Use `strcpy()` to copy.

Comment: Assigning string literals to pointers the way you do here (probably) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: If you could assign strings with `=` you wouldn't need `strcpy`.

Comment: Do you understand what `const char *` means in this case, and why it's a Good Thing?

Comment: @BobJarvis isn't it telling me that it wants a string literal in the calling?

Comment: No: the `const char *` argument says "I, `strcpy()`, promise not to try to modify the string passed as my second argument; I'll read it, but I won't write to it".

Comment: No. The prototype for `strcpy` is `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source)`. In this case `const char * source` means that `strcpy` is not allowed to modify the memory pointed to by the `source` parameter. It does not mean that `source` must be a constant, nor does it mean that `source` must be unmodifiable - it only means that `strcpy` promises that it won't change `source`. Thinking about this differently - if your contention was correct that `strcpy` can only copy *string constants* around, it would be a pretty useless routine, wouldn't it? Well - best of luck.

Comment: Got it. Thank you everyone. I shall use strcpy and research more into string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assigning a string literal to `str2` - the very thing that you claim you aren't doing. This is actually the cause of your segfault.

```
str2 = "hey jude";
```

It also is causing a memory leak as prior to this, you `malloc`'d some memory and assigned it to `str2` as well. But not enough memory to hold the string. Typically an `int` is 4 bytes and you need 9 bytes to store that string.

What you want to do is this, which allocates as many bytes as there are in the string, plus an extra one to store the `\0` terminating character at the end.

```
str2 = malloc(strlen("hey jude")+1);
strcpy(str2,"hey jude");
```

or on some systems you can use POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) which effectively does the job of the above in one handy function call.

```
str2 = strdup("hey jude");
```

Comment: Strictly, of course, you should check the result of `malloc()`.  It isn't critical just at the moment — there are other bigger problems in the original code.

Comment: Writing to read-only memory will cause a SIGSEV. That's why you get segmentation fault on the first line of your `copyString` function : you assign to `str2` the address of a litteral const, and then you try to copy `str` over it.

Comment: Would this explain why if i do `free(str2)` after doing `str2 = "hey jude";` gives me segfault? Because I've assigned a literal to it?

Comment: @riciloma yes, plus it wouldn't be freeing the memory you've allocated as you've already overwritten it

Answer (score 0):

Let's go at it line by line and see where it goes wrong:

```
int main(){
    char * str = (char*)malloc((int)sizeof(double));
    char * str2 = (char *)malloc((int)sizeof(int));
    str = "hello";
    str2 = "hey jude";
    copyStrings(str2, str);
    free(str);
    free(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

`int main(){` - this is an improper definition of `main`. Should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

`char * str = (char*)malloc((int)sizeof(double));` - defines `str`, then allocates (probably) 8 bytes of memory and assigns its address to `str`. `malloc` takes a `size_t` argument, so the cast `(int)sizeof(double)` is incorrect. Also, in C the return value of `malloc` should **never** be cast. So this line should be `char * str = malloc(sizeof(double));`

`char * str2 = (char *)malloc((int)sizeof(int));` - all the same problems as the preceding line. Should be `char *str2 = malloc(sizeof(int));`

`str = "hello";` - causes a memory leak, because the memory you JUST ALLOCATED two lines earlier is now irretrievably lost. You've got two options here - either don't allocate the memory when defining `str` or free it first. Let's do the latter:

```
free(str);
str = "hello";
```

`str2 = "hey jude";` - same problem, similar solution:

```
free(str2);
str2 = "hey jude";
```

`copyStrings(str2, str);` - here you're telling your routine to copy the constant string "hello" over the top of the constant string "hey jude". This will work fine **on some systems**, but will blow up **on other systems**. The question is in the treatment of the constant string "hey jude". If it's stored in modifiable memory the code will work just fine. If it's stored in memory which is marked as being unmodifiable, however, it will blow up. It seems that the latter is the case on your system. To fix this you probably want to go back to the previous line and change it to

```
str2 = malloc(20);
```

That's more memory than you'll need, but it will work just fine.

`free(str);` - you're attempting to free the constant string "hello", which is not dynamically allocated memory. This needed to be done prior to the assignment `str = "hello";`.

`free(str2;` - same problem as above. This needed to be done prior to the assignment `str2 = "hey jude";`.

`}` - correct

Best of luck.